# How to import and set as working folder on Tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I'm new on SVN and tortoise, I googled but can't find the answer. What I want, is to import a local folder into my repository, and bind it, so I can update, check out, etc.

Right now what we do, is to import the a local folder, check-out into a new local folder to bind it, and then, it downloads the previously uploaded content (waste of time). there must be a better way right?

How you can help me thanks!

Comment: [Import In Place](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html#tsvn-dug-import-in-place)?

Comment: No, import in place says: "Assuming you already have a repository, and you want to add a new folder structure to it", It is a new repository

Comment: @franko_camron import in place is exactly what you're looking for. You have a repository (new, empty) and want to import your code into it, making the current directory a working copy at the same time. Whether you import in place into a repository that's empty or one that has 1M revisions in it, it's the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

@crashmstr's hint is correct

**Sample**

Initial conditions:

- new empty repository
- some tree

  ```
  >dir /B /S
  z:\Data\file.txt
  z:\Data\Sub
  z:\Data\Sub\file.txt
  ```

Process:

- Tree imported into repo

  `svn import Data file:///Z:/Repo`

  ```
  >svn ls -R -v file:///Z:/Repo
     1 Badger                сен 23 20:35 ./
     1 Badger                сен 23 20:35 Sub/
     1 Badger              6 сен 23 20:35 Sub/file.txt
     1 Badger              6 сен 23 20:35 file.txt
  ```
- Repo checkouted to the existing Data-dir

  ```
  Data>svn co --force file:///Z:/Repo .
  E    Sub
  E    Sub\file.txt
  E    file.txt
  Checked out revision 1.
  ```

and now it's good Working Copy

```
Data>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: Z:\Data
URL: file:///Z:/Repo
...
```